# Is it possible to eveluate this integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^1\int_x^1 \frac{cos(y)}{y}dydx$$

apparently there is a way to evaluate it so it doesnt converge. I tried the change of variables, but it didnt work. Polar coordinates didnt work for me either. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of integration ,

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{1} \frac{\cos y}{y} dy dx$$

$$=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} \frac{\cos y}{y} dx dy$$
$$=\int_{0}^{1} \left( \frac{\cos y}{y} \int_{0}^{y} dx  \right) dy$$
$$=...$$

---

Or you can also perform integration by parts if you want to avoid drawing the region of integration out an changing the order of integration.

Let $\int_{x}^{1} \frac{\cos y}{y} dy=u$ then we have $du=-\frac{\cos x}{x} dx$, and let $v=x$ so that $dv=dx$. Then we have,

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{1} \frac{\cos y}{y} dy dx$$

$$=\int_{0}^{1} u dv=[uv]_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1} v du$$

$$=-\int_{0}^{1} v du$$

$$=-\int_{0}^{1} x \left(-\frac{\cos x}{x} \right) dx$$

$$=...$$

Comment: Why $\frac{\cos y}{y}$ becomes $\frac{\sin y}{y}$?

Comment: My mistake, I mistakingly took the integrand to be $\frac{\sin y}{y}$ , sorry. Everything will still work the same way though as in my edit @Raffaele